# Time complexity of two nested for loops

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5 ...];    //length n
var b = [7,8,9,0,6 ...];    // length m
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        // time complexity
    }
}
```

In the above code length `n` can vary but length `m` is fixed i.e, array `a` length can vary and array `b` length remains as constant.

Will the worst case time complexity of the above code will `O(n2)` when `n == m`?
or
Complexity will be `O(n*m)` since `m` is constant and complexity becomes `O(n)`?

Comment: If `m` is a constant, it gets amortized, which means the complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: @4castle but in worst case if `n` is equal to `m`, shouldn't be the complexity `o(n2)` ?

Comment: Why is n=m the worst case? It's worse if n is much larger than m.

Comment: Time complexity is an indication of how the duration evolves in terms of *n* as *n* increases to infinity. It does not say *anything* about when *n* happens to be equal to a certain constant.

Comment: it is more a question, why do you need a cartesian product? maybe you could use a differen approach to access the item with hashing and only two separated single loops for every array.

Comment: c.f. radix sort with inputs having a constant number "w" of bits. The complexity is sometimes described as O(n) and sometimes as O(wn). It depends on what you think a "constant" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to understand when you see what happens when you make variables go to large numbers.

In this case, n is a variable and m is fixed. Since they are nested in a `for` loop we get a complexity of O(n*m).

If we say that n = 5 and m = 3 (fixed) then we get 5*3=15 iterations in our loop.

If we say that n = 10,000 and m = 3 (fixed) then we get 10,000*3 = 30,000 iterations.

As you can see a bit clearer here, the only thing effecting the iterations and hence the complexity is the n value. So to answer your question, yes, because m is fixed, the complexity is O(n).